# How to use the default launcher icon provided in android studio project as an ImageView (as is)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, android-icons

I want to use the default launcher icon provided in android studio as an ImageView. I used the `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"` ***XML*** tag in my imageView

But I got this as the result:

[image]

But I want this in my ImageView:

[image]

Comment: `"@mipmap/ic_launcher"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are setting `ic_launcher_background` for this `ImageView` and you got it

till Android 7 app icon was a single image, oftenly called `ic_launcher`. Oreo introduced [Adaptive Icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive), which have two layers - background and icon/logo itself. so you need two `ImageView`s or `LayerDrawable`, the second/top layer will be your icon/logo (`ic_launcher_foreground`? inspect your `drawable` or `mipmap` folders)

note that background layer may get some cuts in device launcher - may be square, but also round, rounded corners all or only one etc. also foreground/icon itself may move a bit, just like visualised under above link - when you use old icon `ic_launcher` on newer devices it won't be exacly same as shown in device launcher

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

Hope this helps...Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Answer (score 0):

The default icon provided by the android studio is actually a combination of two different drawable. See the below picture (you can check the same in your project). You can use the icon as an ImageView by stacking one of the drawable on top of another (which is not a good idea) or you can also directly use `android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`. Just as @Vishnu said.

[image: this]